# VPS с работающим Java приложением не отвечает по своему IP клиенту

Tags: java, сервер, клиент-сервер

Имеется VPS с работающим Java приложением, которое привязывается к порту 4444. Имеется клиентская программа, которая подключается к порту 4444 сервера (по его IP), однако результата нет - подключения не происходит.

VPS на Ubuntu 14.04. В чём может быть дело? Возможно, мне нужно ещё порты VPS как-то учитывать в клиентском приложении?

```
Socket socket = new Socket(ip, 4444); //строка в клиенте, отвечающая за подключение

ServerSocket srvSocket = new ServerSocket(4444); //строка в приложении на сервере
```

На localhost всё работает исправно.

Comment: Сервер запущен через командную строку в putty. Нужно передавать на порт putty, в таком случае?

Comment: Вроде бы подключение через порт самого putty не помагает, даже если задавать этот же порт в ServerSocket на сервере.

Comment: Сервер стоит на SkyHost, но у них там полные root-права, не должно быть что-то в этом плане сломано.

Comment: У меня на сервере `serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT_NUMBER);` с последующим `Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();`, а на одном из клиентов `socket = new Socket(serverIP, serverPort);`, и всё равно работает нормально. Тем более если у вас на localhost-e код работает исправно, то дело вряд ли в коде. Возможно, на сервере стоит и блокирует входящие подключения firewall?

Comment: Убедится что сервер запускается. Как запускается программа? Фоновый процесс или основной? Убедится что порт открывается. Во втором putty ввести команду netstat -n -a | greep 4444. В выводе должно быть 0.0.0.0:4444 LISTEN

Comment: А дополнительное ПО вроде Tomcat ставить не нужно? Я сейчас в этом направлении читаю.

Comment: Порт 4444 точно открывается при запуске сервера:   tcp6       0      0 :::4444                 :::*                    LISTEN      8285/java . Винда с сервером пингуют нормально, что довольно очевидно - я же туда исходник от сервера передал.

Comment: А может быть такое, что это у меня на моем компьютере порт 4444 закрыт?

Comment: Вообще ошибка в том, что превышено время ожидания. Может, просто поднять его?

Comment: Хотя,файлы через putty туда передаются на приличной скорости, вряд ли соединение с сервером занимает настолько много времени.

Comment: Может ли fail2ban блокировать подключение?

Comment: С помощью знающего человека отключил nginx, он был на 80 порту. С него запустил сервер (на 80 порт сокет подцепил), и удалось подцепиться клиентом. Выходит, с портами что-то?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно, блокировал входящее подключение iptables, стало ясно это, когда в iptables -L -n этого порта не обнаружили, а политика входа по умолчанию была DROP: Chain INPUT (policy DROP). 
Пытался отключить его командой iptables -F ещё когда только столкнулся, но это команда намертво фризила сервер, и ничего не чистила.
А открыть порты можно командой:

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
```

Но, если открывать все порты не желательно, можно открыть только конкретный 4444 порт:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 4444 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

Всем спасибо за наводки.

Comment: И сохранить состояние командой service iptables save.